# Why am I getting org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

While trying to run the following program :

```
public class Runner {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Configuration config = new Configuration().configure();
        SessionFactory sessFact = config.buildSessionFactory();
        Session sess = sessFact.openSession();
        Transaction trans = sess.beginTransaction();

        Person p = new Person();

        p.setPersonName("Suhail");

        Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
        set.add("Address-1");
        set.add("Address-2");
        set.add("Address-3");

        p.setAddressSet(set);

        sess.save(p);
        trans.commit();        
    }
}
```

I am getting :

```
SEVERE: IllegalArgumentException in class: pojo.Address, getter method
of property: addressID

Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: 
IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of pojo.Address.addressID
```

I don't know the reason for this. I am trying to make `one to many` association between `Person` and `Address` class.

*mapping xml*:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="pojo.Person" table="person">
      <id name="personID" column="p_id">
          <generator class="increment" />
      </id>
      <property name="personName" column="p_name" />
      <set name="addressSet" table="address" cascade="all"> 
          <key column="p_id" />
          <one-to-many class="pojo.Address" />
      </set>
  </class>

  <class name="pojo.Address" table="address">
      <id name="addressID" column="a_id">
          <generator class="increment" />
      </id>
      <property name="personAddress" column="p_address" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

*POJO:*

*Person*

```
public class Person {
    private int personID;
    private String personName;
    private Set addressSet;

    public int getPersonID() {
        return personID;
    }

    public void setPersonID(int personID) {
        this.personID = personID;
    }

    public String getPersonName() {
        return personName;
    }

    public void setPersonName(String personName) {
        this.personName = personName;
    }

    public Set getAddressSet() {
        return addressSet;
    }

    public void setAddressSet(Set addressSet) {
        this.addressSet = addressSet;
    }
}
```

*Address*

```
public class Address {
    private int addressID;
    private String personAddress;

    public int getAddressID() {
        return addressID;
    }

    public void setAddressID(int addressID) {
        this.addressID = addressID;
    }


    public String getPersonAddress() {
        return personAddress;
    }

    public void setPersonAddress(String personAddress) {
        this.personAddress = personAddress;
    }
}
```

*SQL that created table*

```
CREATE TABLE person(p_id INTEGER,p_name TEXT,PRIMARY KEY(p_id));
CREATE TABLE address(a_id INTEGER,p_address TEXT);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you add to adress set Strings. But in your configuration you specify Address class.So I think your problem in this lines:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
set.add("Address-1");
set.add("Address-2");
set.add("Address-3");
```

You need to change set to `Set<Address>` and add Address objects in set:

```
Set<Address> set = new HashSet<>();
Address address = new Address();
address.setPersonAddress("Address-1");
set.add(address);
```

Comment: okay..Then may be I have my concepts wrong.Will you please explain me the `set` tag inside `person` class.

Comment: @SuhailGupta, I think `set` write correctrly. But if I was you I would be use generics to avoid some problems while work with person

Comment: can we please discuss here @ http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32377/discussion-between-suhail-and-aleksei-bulgak

Answer (score 0):

You can do couple of things without Mapping xml file. Place @Embeddable on ur Pojo of

```
    @Embeddable
    @Entity
    public class Address {
    @Id
    private int addressID;
    private String personAddress;

    public int getAddressID() {
        return addressID;
    }

    public void setAddressID(int addressID) {
        this.addressID = addressID;
    }


    public String getPersonAddress() {
        return personAddress;
    }

    public void setPersonAddress(String personAddress) {
        this.personAddress = personAddress;
    }
}
```

Then on

```
   public class Runner {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Configuration config = new Configuration().configure();
        SessionFactory sessFact = config.buildSessionFactory();
        Session sess = sessFact.openSession();
        Transaction trans = sess.beginTransaction();

        Person p = new Person();

        p.setPersonName("Suhail");

        @ElementCollection//To inform hibernate to save this in a seperate table
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
        set.add("Address-1");
        set.add("Address-2");
        set.add("Address-3");

        p.setAddressSet(set);

        sess.save(p);
        trans.commit();        
    }
}
```

Better to use Annotations so that we get rid of writing .hbm.xml mapping File